# how to navigate to a screen before the stack navigator is created?

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I am new to react and essentially I am using Expo to create an app. I chose the TypeScript setup with the tabs and navigator already implemented when I ran "expo init newApp". I just have a transition screen I want to display for a few seconds before navigating to the root of the app, which is just the component already given to me by Expo (from the template, it contains `tabonescreen.tsx` and `tabtwoscreen.tsx`).

However, I am not sure how to create a new stack navigator, and I believe it is overkill for this situation.

What should I do? How should I navigate to the root after I display my transition:

**App.tsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import useCachedResources from './hooks/useCachedResources';
import TransitionScreen from './screens/TransitionScreen';


// A root stack navigator is often used for displaying modals on top of all other content
// Read more here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/modal
export default function App() {
  const isLoadingComplete = useCachedResources();

  if (!isLoadingComplete) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return (
      
      <TransitionScreen/>
    );
  }
}
```

**TransitionScreen.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Image } from 'react-native';

export default function TransitionScreen() {
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
          style={styles.calpalLogo}
          source={require('../assets/images/calpal.png')}
        />  
        {
            setTimeout(() => {
                //GO TO tabonescreen.tsx/root of the app
            }, 5000)
        }
      </View>
    )
  }


  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#FAFAFA',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    calpalLogo: {
      width:'100%',
      height:'60%',
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return your navigator when loading is complete so meanwhile it is loading your transition is showing and when it finish to load you will get your navigator and can navigate normally.
If you want put your navigator to put a better code.

```
export default function App() {
  const isLoadingComplete = useCachedResources();

  if (!isLoadingComplete) {
    return <YourNavigator/>;
  } else {
    return (
      
      <TransitionScreen/>
    );
  }
}
```